# I need to write a program in Python to calculate the calories burned while doing an activity

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need to use a "for" loop in order to calculate the calories from the user input. Everything is based around the input except for the rate at which the calories are burned. (3.4) per minute.

This is what I have so far. I get the correct answer but it repeats the loop infinitely.

```
time = int(input('How many minutes were you exercising? '))

for i in range (time):
    calories = (time * 3.4)
    calories = float(calories)
    print(calories)
```

Comment: This does not repeat the loop infinitely, it repeats the loop `time` times. If you enter 3, you get 3 loops. So, if that's your actual problem, this isn't your actual code. Please sure us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually demonstrates the problem you want solved.

Comment: Also, is this a homework assignment or an exercise in a book? If so, give us more details of the assignment, because it'll probably be obvious what you've missed. If not, then what makes you think you need a `for` loop in the first place?

Comment: Don't put important information in a comment, edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accumulate the number of calories for each minute.

```
time = int(input('How many minutes were you exercising? '))

calories = 0  
for i in range(time):
    calories += 3.4

print('You burned {} calories'.format(calories))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop; the multiplication that you're already doing is all that's required:

```
time = int(input('How many minutes were you exercising? '))
calories = time * 3.4
print(calories)
```

I've also removed `calories = float(calories)` since it's redundant (when you multiply an `int` by a `float`, you get a `float`).

P.S. If using a `for` loop is a requirement for this assignment, think about what it means to multiply two numbers together.